# Is it possible to dynamically call a cfquery variable?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfquery

I'm going through a query in which there are 12 entries named "choice_1" through "choice_12." I want to be able to dynamically call an individual choice depending where it is in the loop. 
So here is the query:

```
<CFQUERY DATASOURCE="tr3" NAME="qryUserMatchPref"> 
    SELECT *
FROM UsrMatchPrefTR2
WHERE session = #sess# AND site = #siteFirst# AND user_id = #tempUser#
</CFQUERY>
```

And let's say the loop is on it's third run and I wanted to check choice_3, I would want in  theory to do something like this.

```
<cfset combined = "choice_" & counterChoice>
<cfset tempMatch = qryUserMatchPref.#combined#>
```

I would of course be querying for choice_3, if counterChoice is equal to 3, and not for what ever is in the "combined" column [doesn't exist in this case]. Is there a way to do this in coldfusion or am I doomed to create a very tedious series of if statements? D:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should just be able to do

```
qryUserMatchPref[combined][currentRow]
```

Comment: And if your query only returns one record and your not looping over it you can just change [currentRow] to [1]

Comment: Wow, this is perfect and exactly what I was looking for, though I personally had no need for the [currentRow]. Thank you for the speedy response. :) **And than I read your comment and you already explained that. Thank you again. :D**